# How do you send ada from a Byron address to a Shelley address using the CLI?

Tags: testnet, address, byron

I am currently working to build a private network from Byron to Alonzo and I think I have some test-ada left in a Byron address.
If I am in the Shelley (Alonzo) era and I am using the cli to conduct transactions, are there:
 1) CLI commands to look at the UTXO's at a Byron era address?
2) CLI commands to move ada from the Byron era address to the Shelley era address? 
Please let me know if you need any clarification on the questions. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

As Byron does not change address types, we will be still referring to them as Shelley type addresses.

1. To look at your UTXOs, using `cardano-cli`:

```
cardano-cli query utxo \
  --address $(cat payment.addr) \
  --mainnet
                            TxHash                                 TxIx        Amount
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4e3a6e7fdcb0d0efa17bf79c13aed2b4cb9baf37fb1aa2e39553d5bd720c5c99     4         20000000 lovelace
```

2. This is more complicated, but it is well documented in the [`cardano-cli` documentation](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/blob/master/doc/stake-pool-operations/simple_transaction.md), as follows:

Create a draft for the transaction and save it in tx.draft

Note that for `--tx-in` we use the following syntax: `TxHash#TxIx` where `TxHash` is the transaction hash and `TxIx` is the index; for `--tx-out` we use: `TxOut+Lovelace` where `TxOut` is the hex encoded address followed by the amount in `Lovelace`. For the transaction draft --tx-out, --invalid-hereafter and --fee can be set to zero.

```
cardano-cli transaction build-raw \
--tx-in 4e3a6e7fdcb0d0efa17bf79c13aed2b4cb9baf37fb1aa2e39553d5bd720c5c99#4 \
--tx-out $(cat payment2.addr)+0 \
--tx-out $(cat payment.addr)+0 \
--invalid-hereafter 0 \
--fee 0 \
--out-file tx.draft
```

##### Calculate the fee

A simple transaction needs one input, a valid UTXO from `payment.addr`, and two outputs:

- Output1: The address that receives the transaction.
- Output2: The address that receives the change of the transaction.

Note that to calculate the fee you need to include the draft transaction

```
cardano-cli transaction calculate-min-fee \
--tx-body-file tx.draft \
--tx-in-count 1 \
--tx-out-count 2 \
--witness-count 1 \
--byron-witness-count 0 \
--mainnet \
--protocol-params-file protocol.json

> 167965
```

##### Calculate the change to send back to payment.addr,

all amounts must be in Lovelace:

```
expr <UTXO BALANCE> - <AMOUNT TO SEND> - <TRANSACTION FEE>
```

For example, if we send 10 ADA from a UTxO containing 20 ADA, the change to send back to `payment.addr` after paying the fee is: 9.832035 ADA

```
expr 20000000 - 10000000 - 167965

> 9832035
```

##### Determine the TTL (time to Live) for the transaction

To build the transaction we need to specify the **TTL (Time to live)**, this is the slot height limit for our transaction to be included in a block, if it is not in a block by that slot the transaction will be cancelled. So TTL = slot + N slots. Where N is the amount of slots you want to add to give the transaction a window to be included in a block.

Query the tip of the blockchain:

```
cardano-cli query tip --mainnet
```

Look for the value of `slot`

```
{
    "epoch": 259,
    "hash": "dbf5104ab91a7a0b405353ad31760b52b2703098ec17185bdd7ff1800bb61aca",
    "slot": 26633911,
    "block": 5580350
}
```

Calculate your `invalid-hereafter`, for example:  26633911 + 200 slots = 26634111

##### Build the transaction

We write the transaction in a file, we will name it `tx.raw`.

```
cardano-cli transaction build-raw \
--tx-in 4e3a6e7fdcb0d0efa17bf79c13aed2b4cb9baf37fb1aa2e39553d5bd720c5c99#4 \
--tx-out $(cat payment2.addr)+10000000 \
--tx-out $(cat payment.addr)+9832035 \
--invalid-hereafter 26634111 \
--fee 167965 \
--out-file tx.raw
```

##### Sign the transaction

Sign the transaction with the signing key **payment.skey** and save the signed transaction in **tx.signed**

```
cardano-cli transaction sign \
--tx-body-file tx.raw \
--signing-key-file payment.skey \
--mainnet \
--out-file tx.signed
```

##### Submit the transaction

```
cardano-cli transaction submit \
--tx-file tx.signed \
--mainnet
```